# httpkit-fake does not intercept url build with passed parameters

Tags: clojure, http-kit

How can I have `with-fake-http` intercept an `http/get` request containing `:query-params`. The following code produces an exception

```
 (require                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            '[org.httpkit.client :as http]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            '[org.httpkit.fake :refer :all]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            )      


(with-fake-http ["localhost?q=hello" "hello param"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  (println @(http/get "localhost" :query-params {:q "hello"})))
```

> CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to perform GET on unregistered URL localhost and real HTTP requests are disabled., compiling:(web/db_test.clj:57:1)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the String `"localhost?q=hello"`, you can provide a map with the keys `:url` and `:query-params`

```
(with-fake-http 
    [{:query-params {:q "hello"}, :url "localhost"} "hello param"]
    (println @(http/get "localhost" {:query-params {:q "hello"}})))
```